# AngularJS Directive - Restrict: 'A' and set that directive equal to a value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know this is probably some sort of duplicate, but I don't really know how to word what I'm looking for. So I created a directive that is restricted to an attribute. I'm pretty much just wondering how I can allow the directive itself to be set equal to a value. And then use that value in the link function.

For example: Let's say I have a directive called 'myDirective' that is restricted to an attribute. I want to know how I can go about doing something like this

```
<input type="text" my-directive="vm.someValue" />
```

and be able to access that value in the link function of the directive. I know I can just attach a new attribute to the directive via the scope property, but this solution seems much cleaner to me since I only need one value.

Comment: You tried $element.attr('my-directive') ?

Comment: Ohhh, I kept trying to start with $attrs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample of using bindings and ngModel inside the controller and link function together to using the attributes.

[Check this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vu3awLh0s6tnWq8fAiNZ?p=preview) and try to modify the value of the input.

**NOTE:** attrs.$observe() is used to watch for interpolated attributes. This means watching for changes in case you have `<div my-directive="{{someVal}}"></div>`. Therefore in the attached sample the callback will not be triggered because the DOM attribute value does not change as a consequence of interpolation.

**NOTE:** Also bindings provide different behavior like `@` (get string value), `=` (two-way data binding), `<` (one-way data binding).

**NOTE:** In some cases you want to inject the NgModelController in order to work on the ngModel (eg: change flags, change value, interact with validation).

Based on all these usages you can choose your preferred way of doing things.

In case you need to manipulate the DOM you can go with the link function. But in the case you need to manipulate data then might be suitable to use the controller.

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div my-directive="myVal" ng-model="myVal"></div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="myVal" /> 
  </body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restict: 'A',
    scope: {
      // one-way binding
      prop1: '<myDirective',
      // two-way binding
      prop2: '=myDirective',
      // string value
      prop3: '@myDirective',
      // bind to ngModel value
      ngModelProp: '<ngModel'
    },
    require: '^ngModel',
    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop1, () => {
        console.log(`controller - scope - <myDirective - ${$scope.prop1} [${typeof($scope.prop1)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop2, () => {
      console.log(`controller - scope - =myDirective - ${$scope.prop2} [${typeof($scope.prop2)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop3, () => {
        console.log(`controller - scope - @myDirective - ${$scope.prop3} [${typeof($scope.prop3)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.ngModelProp, () => {
        console.log(`controller - scope - ngModel - ${$scope.ngModelProp} [${typeof($scope.ngModelProp)}]`);
      });
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop1, () => {
        console.log(`link - scope - <myDirective - ${$scope.prop1} [${typeof($scope.prop1)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop2, () => {
      console.log(`link - scope - =myDirective - ${$scope.prop2} [${typeof($scope.prop2)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.prop3, () => {
        console.log(`link - scope - @myDirective - ${$scope.prop3} [${typeof($scope.prop3)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.ngModelProp, () => {
        console.log(`link - scope - ngModel - ${$scope.ngModelProp} [${typeof($scope.ngModelProp)}]`);
        console.log(`link - NgModelController - ${ngModel.$modelValue} [${typeof(ngModel.$modelValue)}]`);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => element.attr('my-directive'), () => {
        console.log(`link - element - ${element.attr('my-directive')} [${typeof(element.attr('my-directive'))}]`);
      });

      attrs.$observe('myDirective', () => {
        console.log(`link - attrs - ${attrs.myDirective} [${typeof(attrs.myDirective)}]`);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity! This was a great in-depth example and it showed me a lot of things I haven't seen before. What does "() => " mean inside of your watches?

Comment: They are called "arrow functions" (from ES6). You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for example. Is not a small subject to be added inside a comment :). You can find something similar in other languages but called "lambda expressions". You will find also that wasn't necessary to use arrow functions in this code and normal functions were just perfect. For the sake of semantics there are also cases when to use function and cases when to use an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute via the [`attrs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) parameter of the l[ink function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

```
function linkingFn(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  // get the attribute value
  console.log(attrs.ngModel);

  // change the attribute
  attrs.$set('ngModel', 'new value');

  // observe changes to interpolated attribute
  attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value) {
    console.log('ngModel has changed value to ' + value);
  });
}
```

In your case, you can ask on `myDirective`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the other examples for setting and observing the value as well! That .$observe example probably just saved me a bunch of extra hassle :)